# Method with @OnLifecycleEvent annotation in multiple lifecycle methods

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have the following lifecycle methods in my fragment class:

```
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        releasePlayer()
}

override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if(Util.SDK_INT >= 24){
            releasePlayer()
        }
}
```

As you can see, they both call a method called `releasePlayer()`.
Now, instead using these 2 lifecycle methods I wanted to put the `releasePlayer()` logic from the `Fragment` into an own separate class which implements the `LifecycleObserver` interface. So, whenever the onStart() or onResume() lifecycle methods are triggered, the `releasePlayer()` code in the separate class (observing the lifecycle methods) would be invoked.
For that I have now this:

```
class PlayerLogic(private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) : LifecycleObserver {

  init {
      lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
  }


  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START,Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    private fun releasePlayer(){  // ..do some stuff }

}
```

But using `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START,Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)`
gives me an error telling me that the `@OnLifecycleEvent` annotation excepts only one argument.

So, how can I let `releasePlayer()` be invoked when the `onStart()` and `onResume()` are called.
Is that possible ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just duplicate it

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
fun start() {
    releasePlayer()
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
fun resume() {
    releasePlayer()
}

private fun releasePlayer() {
    // ..do some stuff
}
```

Comment: ooohh, nice solution. Thanks